# Delete newline / return carriage in file output

Tags: python, file, io

I have a wordlist that contains returns to separate each new letter.  Is there a way to programatically delete each of these returns using file I/O in Python?

Edit: I know how to manipulate strings to delete returns.  I want to physically edit the file so that those returns are deleted.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
wfile = open("wordlist.txt", "r+")           
for line in wfile:
    if len(line) == 0:
        # note, the following is not real... this is what I'm aiming to achieve.
        wfile.delete(line)
```

Comment: If you have a dictionary in memory, why would you need to involve the file system?

Comment: You have a syntax error, the if statement is wrong in two ways, its missing the trailing : and you can't assign in an if statement you want to be using ==

Comment: Updating a file at the same time you're reading it is tricky. I suggest you create a new file while reading from the current one that has just what you want in it. The answer below show ways to get rid of the returns/newlines in what's being read.

Comment: Does the wordlist file have carriage-returns/newlines between each letter or between each *word*?

Comment: If you delete the returns in the file there will be nothing separating the letters (or is it words?) from one another. Your code, BTW, looks like it's trying to delete lines with nothing on them, which is impossible since each 'line' will consists of at least the line-terminating newline read (unless the file ends with an incomplete line).

Comment: Hmm.  I meant to say that letters are separated with a blank return carriage (so two 'enters')-- I want to delete that return.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
>>> string = "testing\n"
>>> string
'testing\n'
>>> string = string[:-1]
>>> string
'testing'
```

This basically says "chop off the last thing in the string" The `:` is the "slice" operator. It would be a good idea to read up on how it works as it is *very* useful.

**EDIT**

I just read your updated question. I think I understand now. You have a file, like this:

```
aqua:test$ cat wordlist.txt 
Testing

This

Wordlist

With

Returns

Between

Lines
```

and you want to get rid of the empty lines. Instead of modifying the file while you're reading from it, create a new file that you can write the non-empty lines from the old file into, like so:

```
# script    
rf = open("wordlist.txt")
wf = open("newwordlist.txt","w")
for line in rf:
    newline = line.rstrip('\r\n')
    wf.write(newline)
    wf.write('\n')  # remove to leave out line breaks
rf.close()
wf.close()
```

You should get:

```
aqua:test$ cat newwordlist.txt 
Testing
This
Wordlist
With
Returns
Between
Lines
```

If you want something like

```
TestingThisWordlistWithReturnsBetweenLines
```

just comment out

```
wf.write('\n')
```

Comment: What happens if somehow a string like this gets passed to your "chopper"  "test"[:-1]

Comment: The script which uses `rstrip` did not work for me until I added `rf.close()` and `wf.close()` as last lines - the script opens those files, but it does not close them. Effectively this ended up in an empty `wf`.

Answer (score 20):

You can use a string's [rstrip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) method to remove the newline characters from a string.

```
>>> 'something\n'.rstrip('\r\n')
>>> 'something'
```

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient is to not specify a strip value

`'\nsomething\n'.split()` will strip all special characters and whitespace from the string

Comment: I would be careful with this as `"Business Consultant \n".split()` will return `['Business', 'Consultant']`

Answer (score 2):

simply use, it solves the issue.

```
   string.strip("\r\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove empty lines in the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input("wordlist.txt", inplace=True):
    if line != '\n':
       print line,
```

The file is moved to a backup file and standard output is directed to the input file.

Answer (score 0):

```
'whatever\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\n\n\n\n\n'.translate(None, '\r\n')
```

returns

```
'whatever'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also a possible solution

```
file1 = open('myfile.txt','r')
conv_file = open("numfile.txt","w")

temp = file1.read().splitlines()

for element in temp:
    conv_file.write(element)

file1.close()
conv_file.close()
```