# How to separate datablocks and plot in Python

Tags: python

I have a data file (x and y columns) with different data separated by two empty lines. Is there a way to plot n blocks separately in the same figure using Python?

```
1 1
2 2
3 3

4 5
5 6
6 7
```

This is the code I have tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt from scipy
import * import numpy as np

data=np.loadtxt('data.dat')
i=0
for i in len(data):
    plt.plot(data[i:i+3,0], data[i:i+3], 'ro')
    i=i+4,
return
```

But I seem to be getting a wrong plot. What am I missing?

Comment: using [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) would be my first guess when it comes to plot something.

Comment: how are organized your data ? it come from a .txt file ? have you tried anything ?

Comment: Yes it is, but if you want any help you will have to include the code you have attempted so far, or at least show us where you are stuck!?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to put all of the data on the same plot, then just [ignore the blank lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842057/python-easiest-way-to-ignore-blank-lines-when-reading-a-file):

```
with open('data.dat') as f:
    lines = [line for line in f if line.strip()]

data = [line.split() for line in lines]
plt.plot(*zip(*data), marker='o', color='r', ls='')
plt.show()
```

Otherwise, if you're trying to iterate over each block then you could split the data on the `\n\n` whitespace:

```
with open('data.dat') as f:
    lines = f.read()

blocks = lines.split('\n\n')
for block in blocks:
    data = [line.split() for line in block.splitlines()]
    plt.plot(*zip(*data), marker='o', color='r', ls='')
    plt.show()
```