# How do I make a list from a textfile in Python?

Tags: python

I have a txt file that contains names which are separated by lines but with some empty lines.
When I execute the following code, every second name gets ommitted in the output array.
Why is that?

```
def get_string_list(string_textfile):
    list = []
    file = open("names.txt", "r")
    for line in file:
       line = file.readline()[:-1]
       list.append(line.lower())

    return list
```

Comment: @dumbPy .... readlines() will be lines in a list ... read is a big string

Comment: Change 'line = file.readline()[:-1]' to 'line = line[:-1]'. Every second line is omitted because you are already iterating through the lines in the file via your for-loop.

Comment: im not entirely sure but i think when you iterate a file it strips the newline off for you

Comment: @PaulM. Thanks, that worked wonderfully!

Comment: Since you have blank lines you want to ignore (i.e. only want the names), check [easiest method to ignore blank lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842057/easiest-way-to-ignore-blank-lines-when-reading-a-file-in-python) (basically use strip function).

Comment: @PaulM. Could you post your reply as answer so I can mark it as solution?

Answer (score 1):

when you iterate the file

```
for line in file:
    # you read line just now it exists
    line = file.readline() 
    # uh oh you just read another line... you didnt do anything with the first one
```

dont mix iteration of a file with readline in general (in fact i think modern python versions will throw an error if you try to mix these two)

if all you want is a list of lines you can do any of the following

```
lines = list(file)
# or 
lines = file.readlines()
```

you can get only non_empty lines and strip newlines as follows

```
lines_stripped = list(filter(None,(l.strip() for l in file)))
```

not super pythonic but its nice and terse and pretty clear what its doing

Comment: So by using for line in file I already read a line. I just need to list.append(line) ?

Answer (score 0):

modify for statements like following:

```py
for line in file:
    list.append(line.strip().lower())
list = [name for name in list if name]
```

last line added to remove empty line.