# How would i put strings into an array from another text file (reading line by line) but only reading every other line

Tags: python, python-3.x

(in txt file)

```
line

line

notice that there's a blank line between line
```

I would want the array to look like:
x = [“line”, “line”, “notice that there's a blank line between line”]

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842057/easiest-way-to-ignore-blank-lines-when-reading-a-file-in-python

Comment: What have you tried? How didn't it work as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
txtFile = open("yourfile.txt").readlines()
x = [txtFile[i].strip() for i in range(len(txtFile)) if i % 2 == 0 ]
```

Edit:
If you just want to remove blank lines try replacing the x variable line with

```
x = [txtFile[i] for i in range(len(txtFile)) if txtFile[i] != "\n"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way -

```
with open("file_name.txt") as file:
    result = [line.rstrip() for line in file if line.rstrip()]
    print (result)
```

O/P: `['line', 'line', "notice that there's a blank line between line"]`