# Why does my generator function not return a value

Tags: python

I'm learning python.

I'm trying to read in a text file (Linux: `/etc/passwd`)
I've taken the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842057/easiest-way-to-ignore-blank-lines-when-reading-a-file-in-python) and tried to implement it with my learning's. I know from all my readings many websites state to use readline() (helps with big files).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def nonblank_lines(f):
    rawline=f.readline()
    while rawline != '':
        line=rawline.rstrip()
        print("#'#'#'#'#'",line)
        if line:
            yield line
            rawline=f.readline()

filein="/etc/passwd"
datain=[]
columnnames=['Username','Password','UID','GID','Name of User','HOMEDIR','Login Shell']

with open(filein,'r') as passwdline:
    print(f"passwdline: {passwdline}")
    for line in nonblank_lines(passwdline):
        print(f"Back from function ====, {line}")
        datain.append(line.split(':'))
```

For reference I edited the `/etc/passwd` file and put in a blank line to test my program

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
bin:x:1:1:bin:/bin:/sbin/nologin
daemon:x:2:2:daemon:/sbin:/sbin/nologin

adm:x:3:4:adm:/var/adm:/sbin/nologin
lp:x:4:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/sbin/nologin
sync:x:5:0:sync:/sbin:/bin/sync
```

However, my program keeps returning empty lines instead of each non-blank line in the `/etc/passwd` file:

```
#'#'#'#'#' 
#'#'#'#'#' 
#'#'#'#'#' 
#'#'#'#'#' 
#'#'#'#'#'
```

repeated continuously.

What am I doing wrong. My guess is it has to do with putting a readline after the yield statement, but I have no idea why it would be a problem. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you try this with a file that doesn't have an empty first line?  Did you try using a debugger?

Comment: I'm still learning and have not learnt how to use a debugger yet. Print is my lifeline for now. I did try without empty lines and it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second call to `rawline=f.readline()` is indented too far, so if a line contains nothing but whitespace (so it passes the `while` test, but not the `if line:` test), you stop reading new lines, and just loop forever.

The minimalist solution is dedenting the line properly so it's not controlled by the `if` statement:

```
def nonblank_lines(f):
    rawline=f.readline()
    while rawline != '':
        line=rawline.rstrip()
        print("#'#'#'#'#'",line)
        if line:
            yield line
        rawline=f.readline()
```

but a better solution is to just loop over the file naturally:

```
def nonblank_lines(f):
    for rawline in f:
        line=rawline.rstrip()
        print("#'#'#'#'#'",line)
        if line:
            yield line
```

and avoid calling `.readline()` at all.

Note: There is *one* behavioral difference from iterating the lines of the file like this vs. manual `.readline()` calls: Direct iteration, while faster, will prevent you from calling `f.tell()` on a text file (it costs something to maintain the state needed for an accurate `.tell()` for arbitrary text encodings, so for performance, direct iteration doesn't do so, and just disables `.tell()`).

If you might need to call `.tell()` on the file, you can use 3.8+'s walrus operator (properly, the assignment expression, `:=`) with `.readline()` without doubling your calls to `.readline()`, risking mistakes like this (and similar ones, e.g. using `continue` and skipping the line read):

```
def nonblank_lines(f):
    while rawline := f.readline():
        line=rawline.rstrip()
        print("#'#'#'#'#'",line)
        if line:
            yield line
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've learnt a lot here. Very helpful indeed.