# How to read lines from a file in python and remove the newline character from it?

Tags: python, file

The code for counting the number of inversions in mergesort:

```
count =0
def merge(left,right):
    """Assumes left and right are sorted lists.
    Returns a new sorted list containing the same elements
    as (left + right) would contain."""
    result = []
    global count
    i,j = 0, 0
    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        if left[i] <= right[j]:
            result.append(left[i])
            i = i + 1
        else:
            result.append(right[j])
            j = j + 1
            count+=len(left[i:])
    while (i < len(left)):
        result.append(left[i])
        i = i + 1
    while (j < len(right)):
        result.append(right[j])
        j = j + 1
    return result
def mergesort(L):
    """Returns a new sorted list with the same elements as L"""
    if len(L) < 2:
        return L[:]
    else:
        middle = len(L) / 2
        left = mergesort(L[:middle])
        right = mergesort(L[middle:])
        together = merge(left,right)
        return together

a=[]
inFile=open('a1.txt','r')
for line in inFile:
    fields=line.strip()
    a.extend(fields)
print mergesort(a)
print count
```

where `a1.txt` contains:

```
46
45
44
43
42
```

the list displayed for the integers in the file should be:

```
[42, 43, 44, 45, 46]
```

but the output is coming as

```
['2', '3', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '5', '6']
```

Why so the numbers tens and ones places of the numbers is separated ?

Comment: check this link... http://stackoverflow.com/q/4791080/782145

Comment: inside a for loop utilize a .strip('\n') or .strip('/n') can't remember what of those were the new line

Comment: How does the title of your question relate to your statedl question?

Answer (score 4):

You are doing two things wrong:

- You are not converting text to integers
- You are using `.extend()` to add to the list.

The two mistakes conspire to make your code fail.

Use:

```
for line in inFile:
    a.append(int(line))
```

instead.

Python strings are *sequences* too. Using `a.extend()` adds every element of the input sequence to the list; for strings that means individual characters:

```
>>> a = []
>>> a.extend('foo')
>>> a
['f', 'o', 'o']
```

`list.append()` on the other hand, adds *individual* values to a list:

```
>>> a = []
>>> a.append('foo')
>>> a
['foo']
```

`int()` isn't too picky about whitespace, so even though your `line` values include a newline, `int(line)` will work:

```
>>> int('46\n')
46
```

Answer (score 1):

You use `list.extend`, `extend` accept an iterable and iterate it, it iterates the string letter by letter.

```
>>> a = []
>>> a.extend('123')
>>> a
['1', '2', '3']
>>>
```

I think what you want is `list.append`.

Answer (score 1):

append adds an element to a list, extend concatenates the first list with another list
use a.append(fields) and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('a1.txt') as f:
  a = list(int(i) for i in f if i.strip())

print(a)
```

The last `if i.strip()` is there to skip blank lines.